# Are staticmethod and classmethod in python not callable?

Tags: python, python-3.x, metaclass

I was writing a metaclass to force docstring for class and instance method. Well to my surprise staticmethod and classmethod are not `callable` just like instance method. I am not sure why?

```
class MyMeta(type):
    def __new__(cls, name, parents, attrs):
        print(cls, name, parents, attrs)

        if "__doc__" not in attrs:
            raise TypeError("Please define class level doc string!!!")

        for key, value in attrs.items():
            if callable(value) and value.__doc__ is None:
                raise TypeError("Please define def level doc string!!!")

        return super().__new__(cls, name, parents, attrs)

class A(metaclass=MyMeta):
    """This is API doc string"""
    def hello(self):
        """"""
        pass

    def __init__(self):
        """__init__ Method"""
        pass

    @classmethod
    def abc(cls):
        pass
```

I am not able to understand why are they not callable? They seems to pass my check if I don't define docstring for them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They are not callable. `classmethod` and `staticmethod` are [descriptor objects](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#implementing-descriptors), and they do not implement `__call__`. The [HOWTO](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/descriptor.html#functions-and-methods) actually gives examples of how you might implement them in pure python, so for example `classmethod` objects:

```
class ClassMethod(object):
    "Emulate PyClassMethod_Type() in Objects/funcobject.c"

    def __init__(self, f):
        self.f = f

    def __get__(self, obj, klass=None):
        if klass is None:
            klass = type(obj)
        def newfunc(*args):
            return self.f(klass, *args)
        return newfunc
```

Note, *function objects are descriptors too*. They just happen to be callable descriptors.